# Despliegue de Laravel en Ubuntu Server 20.04 , no funcionan los vhosts

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, apache, virtualhost

estoy intentando montar mi app de **Laravel 9 (PHP 8.1)** en mi apache y me esta dando un poco de guerra y realmente no se porque.

Mi apache tiene **las siguientes configuraciones para los vhosts:**

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/cv_backend.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/cv_front.conf:1)
*:443                  127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:4)
```

En este caso, la problematica es la configuracion llamada **cv_backend.conf** , cuyo fichero de configuracion es el siguiente:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Redirect "/cv_backend" "https://mi-dns/cv_backend"


        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cv_backend/public


        <Directory /var/www/html/cv_backend/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>


        Alias /cv_backend '/var/www/html/cv_backend/public'

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cv_backend_errors.log

</VirtualHost>
```

Se deberia de poder acceder al proyecto de la siguiente manera: `https://mi-dns/cv_backend`,
el problema esta es que cuando voy a dicha direccion me muestra la estructura de ficheros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Otros datos a tener en cuenta

-> He cambiado el `.htaccess` de mi proyecto de la siguiente manera, para que encaje con el alias:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
          Options -MultiViews -Indexes
      </IfModule>

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase '/cv_backend'

      # Handle Authorization Header
      RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
      RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

      # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
      RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

      # Send Requests To Front Controller...
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
```

-> Si accedo la url `https://mi-dns/cv_backend` y luego añado `/public` me lleva a la aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si necesitais mas info para poder ayudarme con el problema, porfavor decidmelo. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Prueba moviendo la línea del Alias por encima de esta línea: `<Directory /var/www/html/cv_backend/public>`

Comment: @masterguru no me funcionó eso.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu problema no esta en esos archivos sino en la cofiguracion del 443 que no has puesto, necesitas hacer una configuracion para tu puerto seguro tambien el 80 lo unico que hace es redireccional al 443 del puerto por defecto donde no hay configuracion y solo esta mostrando las carpetas

Comment: Gracias por responder,  que deberia de hacer otro vhost pero asi ? : `<virtualhost:443>...` ? No tengo ninguna configuracion hecha para ese puerto

Comment: No se muy bien a que te refieres

Comment: si, otra, puedes usar la misma pero eliminas el Redirect y tienes que verificar que tengas certificados para el dominio que usas, si es local estarian en el fichero /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf

Comment: Ya parece estar funcionando, un millon de gracias  de verdad. 
Solo me queda una dudita, como me has comentado, he creado el fichero `cv_backend-ssl.conf` con la correspondientes configuracion para el 443. 

Pero me queda la duda de si es necesario mantener el fichero de configuracion que es casi igual pero que apunta al `:80` o ese no se esta leyendo en ningun momento ?

Comment: hay que mantener los 2 el 80 y el 443